# How to compare columns and return values recursively?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
data_dict = {'factor_1' : np.random.randint(1, 5, 10), 'factor_2' : np.random.randint(1, 5, 10), 'multi' : np.random.rand(10), 'output' : np.NaN}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

I'm getting stuck implementing this comparison:

1. If `factor_1` and `factor_2` values match, then `output = 2 * multi` (Here 2 is kind of a base value). Continue scanning the next rows.
2. If `factor_1` and `factor_2` values don't match then:

   - `output = -2`. Scan the next row(s).
   - If factor values still don't match until row `R` then assign values for `output` as $-2^2, -2^3, ..., -2^R$ respectively.
   - When factor values match at row `R+1` then assign value for `output` as $2^(R+1) * multi$.
   - Repeat the process

The end result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Your data cannot be replicated. can you copy the text in `Out[186]` and paste it to your question?

Comment: you could try using numpy's where or select to make this conditions. (ex: `df['output'] = np.where(df['f1']==df['f2'], df['multi']*2, -2)`), and then making another condition. Or even creating new columns for True False for each condition.

Comment: @QuangHoang I use random number generation, maybe that's why data isn't reproducible. But I think the question itself isn't affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution does not use recursion:

```
# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
data_dict = {'factor_1' : np.random.randint(1, 5, 10), 'factor_2' : np.random.randint(1, 5, 10), 'multi' : np.random.rand(10), 'output' : np.NaN}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

# create a mask
mask = (df['factor_1'] != df['factor_2'])
# get the cumsum from the mask
df['R'] = mask.cumsum() - mask.cumsum().where(~mask).ffill().fillna(0)

# use np.where to create the output
df['output'] = np.where(df['R'] == 0, df['multi']*2, -2**df['R'])

   factor_1  factor_2     multi     output    R
0         2         1  0.419195  -2.000000  1.0
1         4         2  0.685220  -4.000000  2.0
2         1         1  0.204452   0.408904  0.0
3         1         4  0.878117  -2.000000  1.0
4         4         2  0.027388  -4.000000  2.0
5         2         1  0.670468  -8.000000  3.0
6         4         3  0.417305 -16.000000  4.0
7         2         2  0.558690   1.117380  0.0
8         4         3  0.140387  -2.000000  1.0
9         1         1  0.198101   0.396203  0.0
```

Comment: This solution assigns output = 2*multi throughout. I however need to assign output = 2^(K+1) * multi when factor values match at step K+1

Comment: That is not what you indicated in your question: "factor_1 and factor_2 values match, then output = 2 * multi"

Comment: `df['output'] = np.where(df['R'] == 0, 2**(df['R'].shift(1)+1) * df['multi'], -2**df['R'])`?

Answer (score 1):

```
flag = False
cols = ('factor_1', 'factor_2', 'multi')
z = zip(*[data_dict[col] for col in cols])
for i, (f1, f2, multi) in enumerate(z):
    if f1==f2: 
        output = 2 * multi
        flag = False
    else:
        if flag:
            output *= 2
        else:
            output = -2
            flag = True
    data_dict['output'][i] = output
```

The tricky part is `flag` variable, which tells you whether the previous row had match or not.

Comment: I give it a try but get an invalid syntax error at `data_dict{'output'}[i] = output`

Comment: Sorry, I have mentally switched to another language. Corrected.

Comment: For some reason I still encounter an error. I'll see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I present is, maybe, a little bit harder to read, but I think it works as you wanted. It combines

- [`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) in order to make a column based on a condition,
- [`pandas.DataFrame.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to label different groups with consecutive similar values, and
- [`pandas.DataFrame.rank()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) in order to construct a vector of powers used on previously made `df['output']` column.

The code is following.

```
df['output'] = np.where(df.factor_1 == df.factor_2, -2 * df.multi, 2)
group = ['output', (df.output != df.output.shift()).cumsum()]
df['output'] = (-1) * df.output.pow(df.groupby(group).output.rank('first'))
```

Comment: This solution assigns `output = 2*multi` throughout. I however need to assign `output = 2^(K+1) * multi` when factor values match at step `K+1`